# What the meaning of AB+C?

Tags: logical-operators, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, algebra, truthtable

I want to know that what is the truth table and logic circuit gate for following Boolean expression.
**(A+B).(AB+C)**
I have a doubt in what the meaning of **AB+C**
please, I want some help to get through this. It's important to my ICT examination.

Comment: Are you looking for [math.se]?

Comment: `AB` means `A and B`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For AB+C, what you do is ((A and B) or C)